# When will a script task show a pink symbol for the task?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a package which contains a Script task. Inside we are calling one Stored Procedure and based on the result set we are setting some values to package variables.

If we look at the script task, it has a pink symbol on left top.

When will this symbol display?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is?  Can you confirm you are using BIDS Helper, and this is what is showing?  A pink symbol means an expression in is effect for that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's BIDS Helper's Expression Highlighter:

http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Expression%20and%20Configuration%20Highlighter&referringTitle=Home

> Expression and Configuration Highlighter
>   During development of SSIS packages, it can be easy to overlook that tasks or connection managers are controlled by expressions or package configurations. The purpose of this BIDS Helper feature is to give a visual indicator so that the influence of expressions and package configurations can be seen at a glance.

Comment: its an expression highlighter.when this will show for a script task?

Comment: I don't see any direct documentation, but in my experience it will be when some portion of the script task is using an expression.  When you Edit do you have an expresssion in the expression area?

Comment: It doesn't seem to care if you use Varibles that are also flagged as having expressions.

Comment: yes i have given an expression to the script task and i made the connection string as dynamic and still i am not getting the "expression Highlighter" am i missing anything?

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that the triangle IS displaying, so I'm a little confused.  I don't know about connection strings and script tasks, but in general if you have something in the expression area of Script Task's Edit menu AND you have BIDS Helper installed and running - it should put the pink corner on the Script Task's icon

Comment: how to check BIDS Helper installed and running?

Comment: Tools -> Add-in Manager - should be listed and checked, probably want startup checked as well

Comment: Thank you for the help.After selected the BIDHelper Now i got the expression symbol.